# Помогите разобраться в коде программы шифрования

Tags: шифрование

Итак вот код программы, генерирующей ключи по алгоритму RSA. Точнее должна как бы генерировать. Но почему то не получаеться в чем проблема никак не могу понять. Ошибка в 33 строке

```
/home/extra/listing1.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
/home/extra/listing1.cpp|33|error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression|
/home/extra/listing1.cpp|33|error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|

 #include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
using namespace std;

/* Имена ключевых файлов */
#define PRIVAT "./privat.key"
#define PUBLIC "./public.key"

int main()
{
/* указатель на структуру для хранения ключей */
RSA * rsa = NULL;
unsigned long bits = 2048; /* длина ключа в битах */
FILE *priv_key_file = NULL, *pub_key_file = NULL;
/* контекст алгоритма шифрования */
const EVP_CIPHER *cipher = NULL;

priv_key_file = fopen(PRIVAT, "wb");
pub_key_file = fopen(PUBLIC, "wb");

/* Генерируем ключи */
rsa = RSA_generate_key(bits, RSA_F4, NULL, NULL);

/* Формируем контекст алгоритма шифрования */
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname("bf-ofb");

/* Получаем из структуры rsa открытый и секретный ключи и сохраняем в файлах.
* Секретный ключ шифруем с помощью парольной фразы "hello"
*/
int PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(priv_key_file, rsa, cipher,
0, NULL, "hello");
PEM_write_RSAPublicKey(pub_key_file, rsa);

/* Освобождаем память, выделенную под структуру rsa */
RSA_free(rsa);
}
```

Comment: Компилятор пишет, что ошибка в строке 33. А где эта строка в приведенном тексте?

Comment: Т.е. компилятор недоумевает, зачем строка 33 начинается с волшебного слова `int`, и с параметрами PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey напутано. Там, где должен быть указатель на функцию, написано "hello". Оно этого хелла не понимает. Вероятно ваша хелла должна стоять вместо 0, а длина хеллы -- вместо NULL. Ну и ещё одного параметра не хватает по количеству -- доп.параметры callback'а.

Comment: А, вот @alexlz не поленился найти строку 33. 

Там компилятор не понимает, что Вы хотите объявить (он так считает) с типом int и здорово путается с дагностикой (ну сильно зацепила его строковая константа).

Если по делу, то Вы хотели вызвать функцию PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey() ?
В таком случае  нужно  написать int rc = PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(...); 

В переменной rc будет код возврата.

Comment: >`/home/extra/listing1.cpp|33|error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'int (*)(char*, int, int, void*)' for argument '6' to 'int PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(FILE*, RSA*, const EVP_CIPHER*, unsigned char*, int, int (*)(char*, int, int, void*), void*)'|`

Comment: после того как я написал int rc = PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(...); получил вышеуказанную ошибку((

Comment: @avp при переводе несколько сократил мой комментарий. У функций PEM_write_OBJECT (в т.ч. ваша) 7 параметров. 4 и 5 -- пароль на ключ и его длина. 6 и 7 -- callback и её доп.параметры для получения пароля (это предпочтительней с т.з. безопасности). У вас -- 6 и пароль -- 6й параметр (на месте callback). Как решать -- забить пароль в текст (как вы пытались написать, и как я советовал "hello вместо 0") или писать ф. получения -- решайте сами ("крестик снимите или шайкой прикройтесь")

Comment: PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(priv_key_file, rsa, cipher,
"Hello",6, callback);
вот что я написал 
и вот что получилось 
/home/extra/listing1.cpp|33|error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope|

Comment: Вы издеваетесь? `int PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(FILE *fp, RSA *x, const EVP_CIPHER *enc, unsigned char *kstr, int klen, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);` далее `The cb argument is the callback to use when querying for the pass phrase used for encrypted PEM structures (normally only private keys). For the PEM write routines if the kstr parameter is not NULL then klen bytes at kstr are used as the passphrase and cb is ignored.` Ставьте на месте cb и u нули.

Comment: А почему длина - 6?

Comment: @alexlz, он не издевается, он только начал учиться.